# relations of tensor product are relations of original rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, finitely-generated

Given two (finitely-generated, not necessarily commutative) rings $A$ and $B$, given by generating sets $R$ and $S$, respectively, and relation sets $R^*$ and $S^*$, respectively. Is the tensor product $A \otimes B$ given by the generating set $\{r \otimes s \mid r \in R, s \in S\}$ and relations $\{a \otimes 1, 1 \otimes b \mid a \in R^*, b \in S^*\}$ as well as the tensor relations?

Comment: You would have to include the bilinear relations too right? For instance, $\mathbb Z/2 \otimes \mathbb Z/3 = 0$ as we can take $1 \otimes 1 = (3 - 2) \otimes 1 = 3 \otimes 1 - 2 \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes 3 = 0$. But to do this I needed bilinearity of $\otimes$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop that's what I meant by the tensor relations

Comment: Ah my apologies, I misunderstood.

Comment: I think I have an idea. I just need to show that the given ring satisfies the universal property.